# AWS Glue relationalize does not store data to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have loaded DynamoDB table into DynamicFrame and then I ran `relationalize` with following options

```
df_contracts_rel = df_contracts_normalized.relationalize(
    "contracts",
    staging_path=f"s3://data-export-{aws_account_id}-{aws_region}/temporary/relationalized/",
)
```

I am using Glue interactive sessions.

After some time, the job is done but it seems that relationalize did not store anything to the s3 bucket. There was no error.

When I run it multiple times, I eventually run out of space on local storage, so it seems like Glue has been storing data files into the local filesystem.

Why is this happening?
There is no error and the role used by the Glue job has `PutObject*` and `ListBucket` permissions to the bucket.

Comment: Is that the last bit of your glue job? Have you written the results of `df_contracts_rel` to s3?

Comment: No, because all dataframes in the `df_contracts_rel` are empty. There is some problem with entire process which I am unable to track down

Comment: the issue might lie somewhere else outside those lines of code you included. Might help if you add more information.

Comment: I was able to track the problem by checking the root relationalized dataframe. I summarised it in the anwer

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to track the problem down.

It seems that AWS Glue and DynamicFrame has problem when there is some problem during relationalize operation.

I found that the root dataframe in the result produced by relationalize operation had large amount of errors. I used the `errorsAsDataFrame` operation to track the problem.

The problem was also very cryptic and it was caused by the `Decimal` type used in the underlying DataFrames, which was the result of DDB deserialize.

Seems like AWS Glue has problem with Decimal type and it even tried to use it as root relation join key and went into some loop.

All this caused lots of problems and eventually led to depletion of local storage.